# Simple bash script runs asynchronously when run as a cron job

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, cron

I have a backup script written that will do the following in this order:

1. Zip up files via SSH on a remote backup server
2. Dump my local database
3. Transfer my local database via SSH rsync to the backup server

Now when I run this script from the command line in RHEL it works a-ok perfectly fine.

*BUT* when I set this script to run via a cronjob, the script does run, but from what I can tell, it's somehow running those above 3 commands simultaneously.  Because of that, things are getting done out of order (my local database is completed dumping and transferred before the #1 zip job is actually complete).

Has anyone run across such a strange scenario?  As the most simple fix, is there a way to force a script to run synchronously?  Maybe add some kind of command to wait for the prior line to complete before moving on?

**EDIT I added a example version of my backup script.  It seems that the second line of my script runs at the same time as the first line of my script, so while the SSH command has been issued, it has not yet completed before my second line triggers and an SQL dump begins.**

```
#!/bin/bash

THEDIR="sample"
THEDBNAME="mydatabase"

ssh -i /rsync/mirror-rsync-key sample@sample.com "tar zcvpf /$THEDIR/old-1.tar /$THEDIR/public_html/*"

mysqldump --opt -Q $THEDBNAME > mySampleDb

/usr/bin/rsync -avz --delete --exclude=**/stats --exclude=**/error -e "ssh -i /rsync/mirror-rsync-key" /$THEDIR/public_html/ sample@sample.com:/$THEDIR/public_html/

/usr/bin/rsync -avz --delete --exclude=**/stats --exclude=**/error -e "ssh -i /rsync/mirror-rsync-key" /$THEDIR/ sample@sample.com:/$THEDIR/
```

Comment: Do those three lines of the script each end with an ampersand, & ?  Can you include the exact script in your question, along with the cron entry?

Comment: Could you please share your script.

Comment: @jwpat7 I've edited the post to add my sample script

Comment: The multiple overlapping executions idea of @EkriirkE might be right but we can't tell from the info provided.  Perhaps include the cron entry or entries in the question.  Also, you could make a script called `tellprogress` and in your script above add invocations of `tellprogress` before and after any command you think is overlapping.  In `tellprogress`, report the current date and time, and result of `pgrep tar` or `pgrep ssh` (or `ps aux|egrep 'tar|ssh'` if `pgrep` isn't installed) etc – ie, instrument the problem to get enough info to debug it

Comment: @jwpat7 The entries in question are the first two (ssh and mysqldump).  It seems to me that the ssh is actually the problem as it seems to be running asynchronously from the rest of the script.  ie.  the ssh command is triggered (which takes about 40 mins to actually complete), but immediatly after the ssh command is sent, the mysqldump begins.  I have a feeling the ssh command is returning some kind of 'success' to the cron script just from invoking the command, and it is not actually waiting to finish before moving on

Comment: That behavior (the ssh returning immediately) can't be accounted for by what's shown; could there be an & inside the double-quoted tar command in the actual cron job?  Is ssh aliased?  What does `time ssh sample@sample.com "sleep 15"` report if you put in a cron job?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're explicitly using backgrounding (&) everything should run one-by-one, waiting until the prior finishes.
Perhaps you are actually seeing overlapping prior executions by cron?  If so, you can prevent multi-execution by calling your script with flock

e.g. midnight cron entry from

0 0 * * * backup.sh

to

0 0 * * * flock -n /tmp/backup.lock -c backup.sh

Comment: Thanks, I dont think they are overlapped as the cron job runs once per day, and it takes aobut 1hour in total to run the job

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run  commands in a sequential order you can use **;** operator.

; – semicolon operator

This operator Run multiple commands in one go, but in a sequential order. If we take three commands separated by semicolon, second command will run after first command completion, third command will run only after second command execution completes. One point we should know is that to run second command, it do not depend on first command exit status.

Execute ls, pwd, whoami commands in one line sequentially one after the other.

```
ls;pwd;whoami
```

Please correct me if i am  not understanding your question correctly.

Comment: The semicolon just allows multiple distinct commands on one line.  It does not change the execution of a script vs. separating by newline